# Can maths adornments know the "type" of their contents?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

By "maths adornments" I mean things like `\widehat` (from the ams) and their ilk.  Perhaps the following best illustrates what I mean:

[image: widehat spacing]

Code to reproduce:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
A \widehat{\otimes} B \\
A \otimes B \\
A \mathbin{\widehat{\otimes}} B
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Would it be possible to make `\widehat` (and others) "aware" of the type of their input?  By "type" I mean whether the argument is a relation, operator, alphanumeric character, or  ... are there any more?  What it would do is to set itself to be the corresponding type.  Thus, in my example above, `\widehat{\otimes}` would result in `\mathbin{\widehat{\otimes}}` whilst `\widehat{A}` would result in `\mathalpha{\widehat{A}}`.

I realise that there's a potential issue in that the input might be many characters, but for a single character it should be reasonably safe (and one could supply an optional argument to the augmented `\widehat` to override its choice if one disagreed).

(I just noticed this due to a fairly obvious spacing jump in a beamer presentation where I want to add a hat to a character on a slide.  In the end, my transition command looked like:

```
\alt<3->{\mathbin{\widehat{\otimes}}}{\vphantom{\widehat{\otimes}}\otimes}
```

if one isn't bothered about spacing, one can write `\only<3->{\widehat}\otimes`.)

Comment: Sure, they can be made aware of their input.  Can you explain again what they would do with this awareness?

Comment: @Matthew: Whoops!  That wasn't very clear, was it?  Is the edited version any better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can exploit the macros used by ambsy:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\iwidehat}[1]{
  \begingroup
  \math@atom{#1}{\widehat{#1}}
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$a\otimes b_{a\otimes b}$

$a\iwidehat\otimes b_{a\iwidehat\otimes b}$

\end{document}
```

The package bm uses a similar approach in order to distinguish more types; this macro recognizes only relations and operations, the rest is treated as an ordinary symbol.

### Explanation

Here's the definition of `\math@atom`:

```
\def\math@atom#1#2{\binrel@{#1}\binrel@@{#2}}
```

The first macro `\binrel@` does a measure and sets the meaning of `\binrel@@`; since this is used in a group, the original meaning of `\binrel@@` is restored at the end of the group.

```
\let\binrel@@\relax

\def\binrel@#1{\begingroup
  \setboxz@h{\thinmuskip0mu
    \medmuskip\m@ne mu\thickmuskip\@ne mu
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{$#1\m@th$}\kern-\wd\tw@
    ${}#1{}\m@th$}%
  \edef\@tempa{\endgroup\let\noexpand\binrel@@
    \ifdim\wdz@<\z@ \mathbin
    \else\ifdim\wdz@>\z@ \mathrel
    \else \relax\fi\fi}%
  \@tempa
}
```

Here's what `\binrel@` does. First of all it opens a group and sets box 0 with 0 `\thinmuskip`, negative `\medmuskip` and positive `\thickmuskip`. In the box it sets box 2 to the simple argument (`\m@th` is used to avoid the insertion of the `\mathsurround` kern). Then it backs up by the width of box 2 and sets the argument preceded and followed by (empty) ordinary atoms.

Case 1: `#1` is an ordinary symbol or an operator.
The width of box 0 will be zero.

Case 2: `#1` is an operation symbol.
`\medmuskip` glue will be inserted between `{}` and `#1`, and between `#1` and `{}`, so the width of box 0 will be negative.

Case 3: `#1` is a relation symbol.
`\thickmuskip` glue will be inserted between `{}` and `#1`, and between `#1` and `{}`, so the width of box 0 will be positive.

The final trick is to do

```
\edef\@tempa{\endgroup<test>}\@tempa
```

that will do `\let\binrel@@\relax` in case 1, `\let\binrel@@\mathbin` in case 2, `\let\binrel@@\mathrel` in case 3.

Comment: Um, so I just tried to hack `\mathrel` to adjust penalties and it caused strange errors. After a long time I figured out it was because `\overset` went bonkers, and I guess it's because `\binrel@` uses `\mathrel`... Is there a way I can change `\mathrel` but not affect `\binrel@`?

Comment: @user21820 Please, make a new question specifying the details.

Comment: Okay I wrote [a new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566010/how-to-redefine-mathrel-without-breaking-overset). Thanks!