# Math "metaoperator" adding dot and preserving math class

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I want to define a command, call it `\dotted`, that adds a period at the right place next to certain other math characters*: to the right of function-like tokens, i.e. Ord and Op, and to the left of operator-like ones, i.e., Bin and Rel.  This "meta-operator" should of course preserve the spacing of the original "operator".  I came up with the following preliminary solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\dottedord}[1]{\mathord{#1.}}
\newcommand{\dottedop}[1]{\mathop{#1.}}
\newcommand{\dottedbin}[1]{\mathbin{.#1}}
\newcommand{\dottedrel}[1]{\mathrel{.}#1}

\begin{document}
\[x = \dottedord{\sigma}(y) \qquad x = \sigma(y)\]
\[x = \dottedop{\log}(y) \qquad x = \log(y)\]
\[x = y \dottedbin{+} z \qquad x = y + z\]
% This case is special...
\[x \dottedrel{=} y \qquad x \mathrel{.=} y \qquad x = y\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Equation output]

How can I unify the four commands into one, dispatching on the type of the argument -- is there something like `\mathchoice` for math types?  And why do I need to place the argument of `\dottedrel` outside `\mathrel` to get satisfactory spacing?

If there's something more fundamental to improve, I'd be happy to hear about that as well, of course.

*This is [Julia's syntax](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#man-dot-operators-1) for vectorization or "broadcasting", which can be applied to all functions and operators, but that's not really relevant here.

Comment: Possibly useful to you, if you will be applying the operator to a limited set of symbols: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370253/61644

Comment: Another approach might be to pass in the math class as an option, e.g. `\broadcast[ord]{\sigma}` and use `\csname` to generate the `\mathord` command from that.

Comment: Although this is almost the opposite of what you asked, you could also define `\arrayplus`, `\arrayassign`, etc.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks, but all of that is not really better than simply `\mathord{\sigma.}` or `\mathop{.+}`, in my opinion. The question you linked to seems to be asking the same thing, but -- though I don't really understand the expl3 stuff -- it still seems to check a fixed, given list of symbols...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `\binrel@` test defined by `amsmath` (precisely by `amsbsy`) in order to distinguish between `\mathrel` and `\mathbin`. If the test doesn't return one of these, you can define your own for `\mathop` and others; see [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18338/4427) for details about `\binrel@`, the idea for `\phg@ordop` is similar.

If you don't have to support operators with limits this should suffice.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsbsy}% loaded by amsmath

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\dotted}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \binrel@{#1}%
  \ifx\binrel@@\mathbin \mathbin{.{#1}}\else
  \ifx\binrel@@\mathrel \mathrel{.}#1\else
  \phg@ordop{#1}\fi\fi
  \endgroup
}
\def\phg@ordop#1{%
  \sbox\z@{\thinmuskip=0mu$#1a$}%
  \sbox\tw@{\thinmuskip=1000mu$#1a$}%
  \ifdim\wd\tw@>\wd\z@
    % operator
    \mathop{{#1}.}%
  \else
    #1.
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
x = \dotted{\sigma}(y) \qquad x = \sigma(y) \\
x = \dotted{\log}(y) \qquad x = \log(y) \\
x = \dotted{\log} y \qquad x = \log y \\
x = y \dotted{+} z \qquad x = y + z \\
x \dotted{=} y \qquad x = y
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With even better spacing! This is great.