# Why does a backwards R get replaced with a Cyrillic Ya?

Tags: cyrillic, substitution, relsize

I’m considering using a backwards R to represent a reflection (mirroing) operation.  Although I expected \reflectbox to reflect the geometry of the character, somehow the character becomes replaced by a Cyrillic Ya.  \ensuremath{} resolves the issue, although why is a bit mysterious.  Even more mysterious is what mechanism substitutes the character when I suppose relsize reverts to math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}
\Huge

$R$ 
$\reflectbox{\ensuremath{R}}$ 
\\\\\\
$\reflectbox{R}$
$\reflectbox{\protect{R}}$
$\protect{\reflectbox{R}}$

\end{document}
```

[image: R versus Ya]

Can anyone explain what mechanism causes the backwards R to get converted to a Ya?

Bonus points if you can put into concrete terms why using a backward R_p to represent reflection about a plane is a terrible idea.

Thanks!

Comment: That's no cyrillic Ya but a reflected text R. `\reflectbox` treats its argument as text. You want `\reflectbox{$R$}`.

Comment: Oh that makes sense.  Thank you!

Comment: `\protect{` protects `{` which will do nothing if you are lucky and completely break things if you are not. I can't think of any cases where it can do anything useful.

Comment: Seriously, is this meant as a joke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\reflectbox` puts its content in an `\hbox` for manipulations, and its content is therefore in *text* mode; what you are getting there is no Cyrillic Ya but a plain reversed R

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
R$\reflectbox{R}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the argument in math mode then you should use something  like `\reflectbox{$...$}`, even within math mode (that's why your version with `\ensuremath` works).

Here is math version of `\reflectbox` which scales accordingly to the math style and preserves spacing

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mathreflect}[1]{\binrel@{#1}\binrel@@{\mathpalette\math@reflect{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\math@reflect}[2]{\reflectbox{\m@th$#1#2$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$R\mathreflect{R}$
$\scriptstyle P\mathreflect{P}$
$\scriptscriptstyle f\mathreflect{f}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As David pointed out in comment, `\protect` isn't doing anything useful here. In a typesetting context like here you are lucky as it expands to `\relax` and does nothing; in other contexts it might be `\string` or `\noexpand` and will likely go awry.

Comment: Thank you.  Will take some digging to parse those expressions, but looking forwarde to figuring out how it works without the relsize package.  I’m clearly still fumbling around a bit; as a novice, it’s easy to start at a high level, where there are plenty of examples, excellent documentation for packages, and lots of answers here.  However, it’s been more challenging to self-navigate a layer lower to seen what’s going on below, but not too far below separating the LaTeX from the TeX, etc.

Your responses helped me better understand how the mode switching works.  Thanks again!

Comment: @HoochBlake You can start by reading [The mysteries of `\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/82917). The `\binrel@`/`\binrel@@` stuff is quite likely an overkill here. It's descried e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18338/82917).