# In math mode, create a symbol with $\partial$ and $\partial$ fillped horizontally

Tags: symbols

I am writing some document where I use the Jacobian matrix $\partial f(x)$ of some function $f$ at a point $x$. I would like to define a symbol for the Gramian matrix of this Jacobian $\partial f(x) \partial f(x)^T$ and I was thinking that something like having the $\partial$ symbol followed by the same symbol horizontally flipped would help the reading. Any idea on how to do that in math mode ?

Comment: An idea:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656211/82917

Comment: If you are doing a transpose, your symbol should be both reflected AND rotated by 90 degrees counterclockwise. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's a good idea, not only because it's a highly nonstandard symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\gramian}{}{\partial\,{\mathpalette\gramian@\relax}}
\newcommand{\gramian@}[2]{\reflectbox{$\m@th#1\partial$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\gramian f(x)=\partial f(x)\cdot \partial f(x)^T
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also it is very nice looking. Would you have any recomendation on an other way of doing that ? I was also thinking of using $\eth f(x)$ but this is not ideal either. Also any idea why it is tilted ?

Comment: @P.Quinton I find it gruesome, to be honest.  The tilt is the same (reflected, of course), but just *appears* to be bigger.

Comment: Yeah, my brain might explode, thank you very much anyways !

Comment: Actually is there a way to untilt the original and then do exactly the same ? If then we remove the space this might actually be a bit prettier

Comment: @P.Quinton See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80104/4427, but *not* the accepted answer.