# How to determine if a symbol / command is a relation?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I am using `\sim` as a binary operator and was wondering which of the following two was correct:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \[a \sim b\]
    \[a \mathrel{\sim} b\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

which prompted the more general question: **how to know if `\mathrel` is needed with a particular symbol / commmand?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You look at the definition.

```
> latexdef sim

\sim:
\mathchar"3218
```

The initial `3` tells you this is a relation symbol. Similarly

```
> latexdef oplus

\oplus:
\mathchar"2208
```

tells you that `\oplus` is a binary operation symbol.

You can also look in Scott Pakin's “Comprehensive List” with `texdoc comprehensive` or online on texdoc.org where you find `\sim` in table 89 “Binary relations”.

Or you can do a test that can tell you about a symbol being a `\mathrel` or a `\mathbin` (you'd get `\relax` in other cases).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\BinOrRel}[1]{%
  \binrel@{#1}\texttt{\string#1 is \meaning\binrel@@}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\BinOrRel{\sim}

\BinOrRel{\oplus}

\BinOrRel{\sum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's perfect. Out of curiosity, is the "3 is mathrel, 2 is mathbin" documented anywhere that you know of?

Comment: @Clément In the TeXbook, of course.

Comment: Silly me ;-)  Thanks!

Comment: I'd never heard about `\binrel`. It is impressive how we discover new tools every day... Thanks.

Comment: @Sigur Nice, isn't it? You find an explanation at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18338/4427